# Is File >> Export always redundant when you have File >> Save As...?

Tags: language-agnostic, user-interface

Is it better to keep both?  Chose one?  What criteria would you use to select one over the other?  If you had a button you had to name, rather than the menu to store this, would "Export is shorter than Save As" be sufficient criteria to select one over the other?  **Edit:** Would already having a File >> Save or a Save button influence your decision?  I think my fear here is that saving to another name is implied in the As... bit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it is not redundant.

"Save" should be the primary way to save files in formats that don't cause a significant loss / degradation of data.

I would use "Export" for file formats where major loss of fidelity or information is expected (for example, exporting a spreadsheet to txt or csv).

Looking at the inverse operations ("Open" vs. "Import") may be useful -- I think "Open" should be able to immediately read a file, while "Import" may require specifying extra options for parsing it (e.g. marking columns or delimiters to use when getting a table from a txt file).

Export/Import may also imply partial/incomplete support for a format. When I use Save/Open, I'd expect to be able to use the format as the native one, with no loss of data ever.

Comment: Well stated and addressed another issue too.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how this works on other platforms but on the Mac there is the following clear distinction in document-based applications, which has little to do with file format fidelity:

**Save As...** causes all subsequent **Save**'s to overwrite the file you just created using **Save As...**, so **Save As...** modifies the location of the document that you are working with and stores its current state in that new location, while leaving the original copy untouched.

**Export** does not have this effect, you export to a specific path only once, after that a **Save** operation will still save to the location of the document as it was before the **Export** was done.

So, even in an application that supports a plethore of file formats, such as e.g. Excel, which allows you to **Save As...** to various formats of varying fidelity, an **Export** command may still make sense.  In fact it makes way more sense than saving (as) a complicated document to .CSV, seemingly retaining any formatting/graphs/etc. in the document, while affecting any subsequent saves to also save to that same lo-fi .CSV file.

Summarizing:  The fundamental difference is not in file format fidelity, or 'how native' a format is, but the conceptual difference —as I described above— leads to a logical distinction in what qualifies (fidelity) a file format to appear in your **Save As...** choices, and when you might want to relegate it to an **Export** feature.

Answer (score 2):

In most applications I use that have both, the Save As is used to save to a native format, but the Export is used to save to a format that is somehow *lossy* in that if you reopen the file (if that is even possible) some of the information used to create it will not be available any more.

Example: Say you've got a program that generates music.  The editor has a score and some instruments to play.  You can 'save as' and get a standard gmidi format file, which you can later edit some more if you want to change a track.  The export option will also be there to save a MP3, but this won't let you change the file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually consider an "Export" function to have the ability to write the file to a different format than the "native" format for the application. For example, an image editing app might have a "Save as" to save as a different file in the native format, and an "Export" to export the image to a JPEG or other format.

Answer (score 0):

I view [Export] as changing the format of the saved data. Whereas, [Save As] is saving the same format to a different location.

Obviously you could argue this by pointing to the various image editing programs out there where [Save As] lets you do both.